# C# cast derived class to base class exception via reflection

Tags: c#, .net

I have an app that creates classes dynamically using reflection. When deployed, I get an exception when casting a derived class to its base class.  It only happens on 1 in 100 machines. All the classes are in the same assembly. Below are some code snippets and output from a logging message just prior to the casting exception. I'm at my wits end, any help greatly appreciated.

```
//Parent class
namespace Framework.DataModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DataTreeRequest : TreeNode, IDirtyListener, ISerializable
    {
        ....
    }
}

// Derived Class    
namespace Framework.DataModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CADElementRequest : DataTreeRequest
    {
        public CADElementRequest(String name) : base(name){}
    }
}


// Method that uses reflection to create class and then cast to its base class
namespace Framework.DataModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DataModelBuilder : CoreBuilder
    {
        ...

        protected DataTreeRequest CreateDataTreeRequest(String asmName, String inName, String inType, String inSourceName)
        {
            DataTreeRequest dtr = null;

            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(asmName);
            if (asm == null)
            {
                throw new BaseException("Can't find assembly " + asmName);
            }

            Type requestType = asm.GetType(inType);
            if (requestType == null)
            {
                throw new BaseException("Can't find class of type " + inType + " in assembly " + asmName);
            }

            // Call the constructor for the tree node that takes the xml node as an argument
            Type[] constructorArgsTypes = new Type[1];
            constructorArgsTypes[0] = typeof(String);
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = requestType.GetConstructor(constructorArgsTypes);
            if (constructorInfo == null)
            {
                throw new BaseException("Can't find constructor for type " + inType + " that takes a String param");
            }

            Object[] constructorArgs = new Object[1];
            constructorArgs[0] = inName;
            Object newObj = constructorInfo.Invoke(constructorArgs);

            // Code fails on this line trying to cast derived class to base class on 1 in 100 machines
            dtr = newObj as DataTreeRequest;
            if (dtr == null)
            {
                throw new BaseException("Can't cast newObj to type DataTreeRequest. newObj = " + newObj + ", Type = " + newObj.GetType().ToString());
            }

            dtr.InSource = inSourceName;

            return dtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Logging output on failed machine:

> Message = Found assembly=Framework.DataModel, Version=1.0.5885.31486,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Message = newObj
>   AssemblyQualifiedName=Framework.DataModel.CADElementRequest,
>   Framework.DataModel, Version=1.0.5885.31486, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, BaseType==Framework.DataModel.DataTreeRequest,
>   FullName==Framework.DataModel.CADElementRequest
>
> BaseException: Can't cast newObj to type DataTreeRequest. newObj =
>   Name=Substations;InType=;InName=Substations;OutName=Substations;InSource=;OutSource=;,
>   Type = Framework.DataModel.CADElementRequest

Comment: Add an assertion for `newObj.GetType().BaseClass == typeof(DataTreeRequest)`. Should fire. Also, add logging for the fully qualified type names involved. Are there maybe multiple versions of the same assembly? Maybe deployment error?

Comment: It is already on the error message "BaseType==Framework.DataModel.DataTreeRequest,"

Comment: @CodeNotFound that's just the type name, assembly is missing.

Comment: Maybe try adding a check for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) and add more logging/details in the exception like [Type.Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.module(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried testing newObj.GetType().BaseClass == typeof(DataTreeRequest) and indeed it is false.  I also tried to create the DataTreeRequest parent object using the same style code as when the CADElementRequest is created.  Works fine.  The assembly version is identical.  The app is deployed in a massively long directory path with GUIDs, etc using App-V.  Is there a full path length limit in .NET?

Comment: I will try Type.IsAssignableFrom tomorrow.

Comment: Why not using [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx)? When it works on other machines, then there is a problem particularly with the environment. Make sure you have same `dlls`.

Comment: I can't see where your log output comes from but clearly the exception message states that `InType` is empty. So the type of `newObj` will not be a `DataTreeRequest`. But I wonder why the null-check then won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(asmName);
if (asm == null)
{
    throw new BaseException("Can't find assembly " + asmName);
}

Type requestType = asm.GetType(inType);
```

with

```
Type requestType = Type.GetType(inType)
```

where inType is assembly qualified name 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need load assembly that is not referenced by project consider using Assembly.Load method.

About disadvantages of using Assembly.LoadFrom read Remarks section in https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/1009fa28(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Answer (score 0):

the red flag is it fails on specific machines (1 out of 100) - how many machines in total does the code fail on? This indicates that it might be the configuration of the machine rather than the code. It also makes it extremely difficult to replicate in order to help.

If it were me. I'd take a step back and simplify the situation. Write code that just does the failing task, even with other simpler classes, and then focus on a failing machine. Get as much information as possible and build up understanding.

It's likely to be referent pain. The situation your facing is only a symptom of the real problem. You're focused on the code but that's just a symptom. That's why it would be good to simplify.

Hope this helps, I'm new to stackoverflow and I know there are rules to follow for questions. I'd have made this a comment but I don't have the reputation for that.